# Do other feminine geographical proper nouns ending in the soft sign have the same declension stress pattern as Русь?

Tags: ударение

Besides Русь, which has stressed endings in the genitive, dative and prepositional cases (Руси́) and stem stressed instrumental (Ру́сью), are there other soft-sign feminine geographical proper nouns having this declension stress pattern?

Besides Русь, I've found only Обь, Пермь and Тверь. Are there others?

Comment: Why they necessarily should be geographical?

Comment: Because the declension stress patterns for third declination geographical proper nouns are poorly explained in grammars such as Terence Wade's.

Comment: @MrDudulex: I'm not aware of any declension pattern which would only work for toponyms. This particular one also works for _степь, ось, грудь, глушь_ and a couple of dialectal words. Third declension is particularly tricky because its nouns readily change even gender, not to mention stress pattern, but it happens with toponyms and non-toponyms alike

Comment: plus one to what @Quassnoi says - I'm not sure that in this particular case there's anything toponym-specific.

Comment: @shabunc: Ok. Besides Русь, do you know any third declension proper noun with mobile stress which isn't a toponym? I would be glad to know.

Comment: Кемь   ........ ......

Comment: Степь, Тюмень, Сень (город)

Comment: Also Грязь (a village near Moscow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wiktionary search is a little bit weird, and the categorization is not ideal.

But if you enter these two queries:

- [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/Категория:Существительные,_склонение_8f"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5,_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_8f%22)
- [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/Категория:Существительные,_склонение_8f''](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5,_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_8f%27%27)

they'll come back with these toponyms: *Обь, Омь, Пермь, Русь, Томь, Кемь, Керчь, Тверь*

Comment: It seems people [tend](https://youtu.be/oTRP5L0l78o?t=194) [to](https://youtu.be/z5EnTqHqq6s?t=108) [say](https://youtu.be/MBvJQoM8Ono?t=16) *Запорожской Сечи́* in genitive. But this is most likely a new trend.

Answer (score 4):

[This search](https://gramdict.ru/search/?index=8&stress=f%27%27) in Zalizniak's *Grammatical Dictionary* also gives **Кеть**, besides those already mentioned.